Counting supersingular elliptic curves over finite fields
I'm reading Elliptic Curves Number Theory And Cryptography (2nd Edition) and the following snippets have confused me a bit:
First excerpt - change of variables
p132

If we have two elliptic curves $E_1$ and $E_2$ defined over a field such that $E_1$ can be transformed into $E_2$ by a change of variables defined over some extension field, then $E_1$ is supersingular if and only if $E_2$ is supersingular.

Second excerpt - roots of $H_p$
p133

THEOREM 4.34
Let $p$ be an odd prime. Define the polynomial
$$H_{p}(T)=\sum_{i=0}^{(p-1)/2}\binom{(p-1)/2}{i}^{2}T^{i}$$
The elliptic curve $E$ given by $y^{2}=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$ with $\lambda\in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is supersingular
if and only if $H_{p}(\lambda)=0$.

p136

PROPOSITION 4.38
$H_{p}(T)$ has $(p-1)/2$ distinct roots in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$.

Questions
Assuming $p \ne 2$, am I correct in saying that every elliptic over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$ corresponds to a unique $\lambda \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$? And vice versa?
It seems that 4.38 and 4.34 $\implies$ the number of supersingular elliptic curves over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$ is $\frac{p-1}{2}$.
If the above 2 points are true, then does this mean there are only $\frac{p-1}{2}$ change of variables over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$ for a given elliptic curve $E$? That seems really strange to me. There is a change of variables mentioned in the textbook that preserves the j-invariant: $(x,y) \rightarrow (\mu^2x, \mu^3y)$; but $\mu$ can take any value inside $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$, so doesn't that mean there are more than $\frac{p-1}{2}$ change of variables for $E$? Which would mean there are more than $\frac{p-1}{2}$ supersingular curves?


Assuming $p \ne 2$, am I correct in saying that every elliptic over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$ corresponds to a unique $\lambda \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$? And vice versa?

No: An elliptic curve given by $E_\lambda : y^2 = x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$ has $j$-invariant $j_\lambda=2^8\frac{(\lambda^2-\lambda+1)^3}{\lambda^2(\lambda-1)^2}$. Generically the map $\lambda\mapsto j_\lambda$ is six-to-one, so given an elliptic curve $E/\overline{\Bbb {F}}_q$ the are usually six $\lambda$ such that $E\cong E_\lambda$ (the exceptions are $j=0, 1728$ where there are only two resp. three choices for $\lambda$ and you also need to be careful in characteristic $3$).

It seems that 4.38 and 4.34 $\implies$ the number of supersingular elliptic curves over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$ is $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

No: Because generically six values of $\lambda$ correspond to the same elliptic curve (up to isomorphism) the number of supersingular elliptic curves is of magnitude $\frac{p}{12}$. The exact number is a bit more difficult because $\lambda\mapsto j_\lambda$ is not always six-to-one, it is given by $\lfloor \frac{p}{12}\rfloor +b_p$ where $b_p=0,1,1,2$ in the cases $p\equiv 1,5,7,11\pmod {12}$ (see Silverman's AEC Theorem V 4.1 (c)).
As for your last question there are a lot of change of variables as you mentioned, but only few of them preserve the Legendre form.

I think I didn't explain myself very well in the question. Suppose I have some supersingular $E_0$ defined over $\overline{F}_p$: $y^2=(x-e_1)(x-e_2)(x-e_3)$. You can use a change of variables $f_1$ to take $E_0$ to $E_1$ in Legendre form, with $\lambda_1$. From here choose another change of variables $g_2$. If you are not in Legendre form then use c.v. similar to $f_1$, say $f_2$, to get you to Legendre form again ($E_2$, $\lambda_2$). According to the textbook, I can only repeat this process $\frac{p-1}{2}$ times because that's how many $\lambda$ values are available.

...but that seems strange since there are surely more than $\frac{p-1}{2}$ options for $f_i ∘ g_i$?

There are a lot of possibilities for $g_2$, but only very few for the composition $f_2\circ g_2$. If $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$ and you do the change of variables $x\to u^2 x+r, y\to u^3y$, the resulting equation is $y^2=(x+u^{-2}r)(x+u^{-2}(r-1))(x+u^{-2}(r-\lambda))$. There are only finitely many choices for $u,r$ such that this is again in Legendre form

So can we say that there are only $\frac{p-1}{2}$ possibilities for $f_2∘g_2$?

No. The number of supersingular curves (up to isomorphism) doesn't really have anything to do with the number of possible coordinate changes that turn a Legendre form again into Legendre form as the resulting curve would be isomorphic to the original curve.
